# NearbyConnection: payload.asFile().asJavaFile() is null when retrying to saveFile after storage permissions initially not granted

Tags: react-native, google-nearby

Hey everyone I'm not sure where this issue originates whether in a react-native wrapper for google Nearby Connections (https://github.com/butchmarshall/react-native-google-nearby-connection) or within Nearby Connection itself. I'm having trouble retrying saving a file payload when permissions are initially not granted because the library states that `payload.asFile().asJavaFile()` is null. The two scenarios are as follows:

**Scenario 1)** Read/Write storage permissions are given, users exchange data via Nearby Connection, `saveFile(serviceId,endpointId,payloadId)` is called and the file is saved without an issue.
**Scenario 2)** User has not granted storage permissions and `saveFile(serviceId,endpointId,payloadId)` is called which returns a rejected promise as expected. The parameters  `serviceId, endpointId, and payloadId` are stored elsewhere so that the user can be prompted to grant permissions and retry saving. Upon retrying, the execution fails as `payload.asFile().asJavaFile()` returns null.

I ran `adb logcat` during both the successful execution (initially granted permissions) and the failure case(retrying after permissions have been granted) and I cannot see a difference when logging the payload. Below are the logs for the failure case:

```
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: saveFile from service com.google.myApp.v1 and endpoint hT4- and payload -6821529802993021226
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: Payload com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.Payload@16edba2
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: payload.getType() 2
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: payloadFileData  awesomePhoto.WEBP:{"description":"a flower"}
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: payloadFilename awesomePhoto.WEBP
03-24 14:31:03.805 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: payloadMetadata {"description":"a flower"}
03-24 14:31:03.806 24644 26856 V NearbyConnection: Cannot convert to file.
```

The `Cannot convert to File` is what is returned here on **Line #1501** https://github.com/butchmarshall/react-native-google-nearby-connection/blob/44f1699812c1f9cce37440294d7de1df438b75af/android/src/main/java/com/butchmarshall/reactnative/google/nearby/connection/NearbyConnectionModule.java#L1501 when `payload.asFile().asJavaFile() == null`. What I find confusing is that it seems that the payload itself exists from what I logged in `adb logcat` as `payload.getType()` worked fine returning 2.

**Question 1**: Does the initial permissions failure cause the payload file content to somehow be destroyed within the NearbyConnection cache so there is nothing to call `payload.asFile().asJavaFile()` on? I find it strange that calling `payload.getType()` works but `asFile()` fails.

**Question 2**: Is it possible to store NearbyConnection payload files within the internal app making the request, obviating the need to request/grant permissions to external storage?

```
When a file is received, it is saved in the Downloads folder (DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) on the recipient's device with a generic name and no extension.
```

src: https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data#file

Assumption/Hypothesis: After the final payload is delivered, Nearby Connections attempts to write the file which, if the permissions are not given, fails. Therefore, regardless if permissions are then granted after, that final payload will still not have a file associated and, as such, will forever fail. If this is correct then there is no other option than to resend the file I'm guessing?

Incorrect I believe:~~ I'm assuming at some point this filedata is garbage collected as it would ultimately fill the app to have this hanging around throughout the entirety of the app lifecycle. Is this happening immediately though in this case? ~~

Any thoughts here would be greatly appreciated.

*Github issue*: https://github.com/butchmarshall/react-native-google-nearby-connection/issues/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is saved despite your app not having READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. This is because Play Services APIs are run in a privileged process, separate from your app. Even though your app lacks permissions, Play Services can still write files. Running in a separate process does, unfortunately, prevent Nearby Connections from writing to your private app storage. And it also means that, even though you cannot read the file, you're still in charge of cleaning up the file or it'll remain on disc indefinitely.

To explain more about the issue, due to the lack of permissions, you cannot read the file. This failure is cached at the point that you get onPayloadReceived. I'll file a bug to avoid caching the failure, but it'll take a long time to fix and ship a new SDK. The workarounds are either...

- Request the permission sooner, before the file is sent to your device.
- Look up the file manually via ~/Downloads/Nearby/{payloadId}. Note that this is not recommended, since the file path may change at any time (although it's unlikely). This is akin to using reflection.

Comment: Thanks Xlythe! Really appreciate it. To be clear I'm assuming the cached failure means that regardless of the fact that I grant permissions after the failure, I will still experience a failure in trying to access the file again through `payload.asFile().asJavaFile() ` even when permissions are granted. As for the context to the problem, I've tried requesting permissions sooner but sometimes users deny it by accident leading to me to prompt the users to go back and enable it. The second step might help though since the file is temporary. Thanks again!